# Unity 3D engine for Ubuntu?

Tags: unity

Is there any way to get Unity 3D to run on Ubuntu. I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04 64bit edition. I also have Wine installed.

Comment: To add confusion to matters, the new UI for Ubuntu is called Unity! It makes searching for Unity issues a bit tricky.

Comment: @Kylotan, I try to differenciate it as `Unity3D` in google, which gives me good results.

Comment: Take a look at this youtube video that shows how to open Unity3d editor under Wine: [How to install Unity3D 4.1 on Ubuntu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wa26vR51PkQ)

Answer (score 7):

According to [Unity's bizarro-world SO](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/63784/can-i-use-unity-with-ubuntu.html) the answer is no.  The Unity3D authoring program is only available for Windows or Mac OS.

Answer (score 4):

According to [WineHQ AppDB](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=11075) Unity3D versions 3.3.0 and prior might work via wine.

Here's a link for 3.3.0: http://download.unity3d.com/download_unity/UnitySetup-3.3.0.exe

Answer (score 3):

It's been years since this question was done, but Unity has started to develop the editor for Linux.

More info on the link
http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/07/01/the-state-of-unity-on-linux/

Answer (score 2):

My answer is **perhaps**.

I tried to run Unity3d 4 with the same configuration. Installs flawlessly, but when you try to run it, it fails at start when trying to checking license for activation.

I wonder if there is some manner to bypass that step. For example, I was able to run the activation part on a Windows XP running within an VirtualBox, so perhaps moving some archive from that VirtualBox install to the wine one may do the trick. Just wonder...

On the other hand it didn't work fine neither on my VirtualBox. Windows are not drawn correctly and crashes after a few seconds.

Comment: I finally gave up and reinstalled Windows Vista in my laptop just for running Unity. Sad day...

Answer (score 1):

You have to use winetricks to improve several parts of WINE for compatibility sake before it will work.  Fonts, DirectX, force Mono, and you have to edit the registry.  More details are out there.

[Video of someone doing it on 12.10](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wa26vR51PkQ)